# Getting error while reloading webapp in pythonanywhere

Tags: python, django, pythonanywhere

I am trying to write my first django app on pythonanywhere with the help of django documentation(Part 1). All the things are successful until I try to add a new file named urls.py and polls app as mentioned in Documentation, I can't reload my webapp after that..I am getting following error:

"Your webapp took a long time to reload. It probably reloaded, but we were unable to check it".

There is no error in my code as I have checked through this command "python3 manage.py check".

As a beginner, Any help would be appreciated.
I am also following the tutorial "Django for everybody" on coursera and followed the instructor step by step, But I can't get rid of this error.

My error log:

1. 2020-08-23 06:55:44,929: OSError: write error
2. 2020-08-23 06:55:48,951: Not Found: /polls
3. 2020-08-23 08:56:52,660: Not Found: /polls

Update:
Issue is resolved by making webapp with manual configuration instead of selecting Django.

Comment: Can you please edit your post and add your code? It isn't always possible to know what the cause of the bug without actually seeing the code.

Comment: There is no code as most of them are some changing to files and code but I have followed this link : https://www.dj4e.com/assn/dj4e_install.md

Comment: Did you use the command `python3 manage.py startapp polls` when inside your project directory?

Comment: Yes I have used this command and after that added some code in polls/view.py as mentioned in documentation

Comment: Okay, so you did add some code, can you show it?

Comment: Thanks for helping. Issue is resolved by making webapp with manual configuration instead of selecting Django.. I will edit the question also..